# Docker image behaves different on different machines

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker, dockerfile

I generated a Docker image that behaves differently on different machines. Something I thought isn't possible with Docker. But let me explain:

My plan is to generate a dashing based Docker image which I upload to an ec2 instance and then start it there.

In the Dockerfile (see below) I create a new dashing instance which creates some jobs (e.g. twitter.rb) in the jobs subfolder. Afterwards I delete the jobs folder and re-create it again to get rid of all default jobs.

When I run the image on my local machine (OS X with Docker Toolbox 1.8.3) I can see that the default jobs were deleted (as expected). Also on the machine of my colleague (Ubuntu with Docker 1.7.1) it works like expected. But on an ec2 machine (modified Amazon Ami with Docker 1.7.1) I can see the default jobs in the jobs subfolder as well as the ones I added at the end of the Dockerfile.

Does anyone know what the problem is? Or give me at least some hints how to proceed?

```
# Build script where 1 is my version
docker build -t dashboard:1 .
docker save -o dashboard.tar dashboard:1

# On the ec2 machine 
docker load -i dashboard.tar
docker run -t dashboard:1 dashing start
```

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install npm && \
    apt-get -y install nodejs && \
    gem install dashing && \
    gem install bundle

# Creates default jobs like jobs/twitter.rb
RUN mkdir /dashing && \
    dashing new dashing && \
    cd /dashing && bundle

WORKDIR /dashing

# Clean default jobs and re-create the folder
RUN rm -rf jobs && mkdir jobs && \
    rm -rf dashboards && mkdir dashboards && \
    rm -rf widgets && mkdir widgets && \
    rm -rf public && mkdir public

# Add jobs from current repository
ADD jobs /dashing/jobs
ADD config/config.ru /dashing/config.ru
ADD dashboards /dashing/dashboards
ADD widgets /dashing/widgets
ADD public /dashing/public

# Run Bundle in a cache efficient way
WORKDIR /tmp
ADD config/Gemfile /tmp/
ADD config/Gemfile.lock /tmp/
RUN bundle install

WORKDIR /dashing

CMD ["dashing start"]
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, if you still have this problem, it sounds like this is a 'default umask' issue with the folder when it is created.  The 'user' running your script must be in a group that has at least 'rw' (read/write) permissions on the jobs directory and the directory above the jobs directory to delete it - sounds like you don't have this on the cloud setup (but obviously you would on your own box!)

(much more detail and credit to [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7466/](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7466/i-cant-delete-a-file-that-i-have-write-permissions-for-as-a-group-member))